# update Nested Array value mongo

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Hello folks struggling with this updatation
Any one can please help out here

```
  "sheet_types": [
    {
      "areas": [
        "FRONT",
        "SIDE",
        "UPPER"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to update the value of **UPPER** to **TOP** here

I have tried this query

```
db.company_settings.updateOne(
   {"sheet_types.areas": "UPPER" },
   { $set: {   "sheet_types.$.areas" : "TOP" } })
```

But the result i getting is

```
{
  "sheet_types": [
    {
      "areas": [
        "TOP"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using "arrayFilters" seems to fit best for this use case:

```
db.collection.update({},
  {
   "$set": {
     "sheet_types.$[].areas.$[filter]": "TOP"
   }
  },
  {
  "arrayFilters": [
     {
       "filter": "UPPER"
     }
   ]
 })
```

Explained:

Add arrayFIlter with one filter element equal to the value that you need to replace , use this filter to replace the value in the update statement. The advantage of this option is that it will replace all matching values that match the filter conditions in the document.

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PmKnW3knvJ3)